# Azure B2C: Enable other devs to access B2C Tenant via their Microsoft Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up an Azure B2C tenant using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant).

This creates a new AD for B2C that is separate to our company AAD (If I try to add B2C on the companys' main Azure AD, it states it is 'not a B2C tenancy', so I went with the tutorial and created a new B2C Tenancy).

When I (the creator of the B2C tenant) log in, I can access the company AAD and the B2C Tenant (details obfuscated). My standard Office365 shows both.

[image]

However, other developers in the team can't see the B2C Tenant.

I want them to be able to access it via their Office365 credentials.

Looking online, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant) and [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-azure-ad-b2c-to-azure-ad-via-the-b2c-custom-identity-provider-42fbc2832e32), but they both seem to be about logging people from your company AAD *into your app*, rather than inviting other devs as administrators. I tried the former to get a developers records in the User table, but after giving them rights, they still cannot see the B2C Tenant.

I then tried to [Add A Connected Organisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-organization), but I still can't access people from the main tenant to give them access.

The Invite users from the Portal doesn't seem to offer the choice of a Microsoft Login. If I try 'Create User', the domain doesn't show and 'Invite User' seems to make them Guests with non-work logins.

[image]

I don't want to set the devs up with 'non-work' logins, as that seems a bit messy.

How do I add other developers from the company AAD to my B2C Tenant using their work credentials (Office365/Azure AD) so they too can also administer the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Need to choose the `Guest User` and choose `Invite User` and after providing the User information assign the role as `Application administrator` or `Global Administarator`. Once you invite the user will recive a invitation to access the B2C tenant. They can Access the B2C Tenant with there own credentials.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am wanting them to log in with their Office365 credentials, not ones they make up there and then. Will this do that? I thought this would require them to make a new login. The other devs have gone home now, so I'll try with one of them in the morning. Thanks again. J

Comment: If the invited email is registered in Azure AD, the invite will force the user to use those.